# Python, parsing JSON-order by/sort by

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON data:

```
 "InstanceProfileList": [
                {
                    "InstanceProfileId": "AIPAI6ZC646GGONRADRSK", 
                    "Roles": [
                        {
                            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                                "Version": "2012-10-17", 
                                "Statement": [
                                    {
                                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
                                        "Effect": "Allow", 
                                        "Principal": {
                                            "Service": [
                                                "ec2.amazonaws.com", 
                                                "ssm.amazonaws.com"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }, 
                            "RoleId": "AROAJMI3DEQ4AW5JJMFII", 
                            "CreateDate": "2018-03-23T15:23:28Z", 
                            "RoleName": "ec2ssmMaintWindow", 
                            "Path": "/", 
                            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:role/ec2ssmMaintWindow"
                        }
                    ]
```

I use the following code to parse it:

```
def get_user_group_service(element):
    s = ''
    for e in element['AssumeRolePolicyDocument']['Statement']:
        p = e['Principal']
        if 'Federated' in p:
            s += p['Federated']
        if 'Service' in p:
            obj = p['Service']
            if type(obj) is str:
                s += obj  # element is string
            else:
                s += ''.join(obj)  # element is array of strings
        if 'AWS' in p:
            s += p['AWS']
    return s
```

Now, the issue is that sometimes the `Service` element contains:

```
ec2.amazonaws.com ssm.amazonaws.com
```

and sometimes:

```
ssm.amazonaws.com ec2.amazonaws.com
```

The order is different every time.

It really doesn't matter in which order it will be shown, I just need the output to be consistent. Is there any way to order this output alphabetically?

I googled it and it seems `obj.sort()` will fix it but don't know how to apply it.

Comment: what exactly want as output?

Comment: sometimes `ec2ssmMaintWindow,AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole,ec2.amazonaws.com ssm.amazonaws.com` and sometimes `ec2ssmMaintWindow,AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole,ssm.amazonaws.com ec2.amazonaws.com` part after second comma changes order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want a sorted string which are space separted. Here is my approach.

```
x = 'ec2ssmMaintWindow,AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole,ec2.amazonaws.com ssm.amazonaws.com'
sorted_only_space_sparated = [ ' '.join( z for z in sorted(y.split(' '), reverse=True)) for y in x.split(',')]

print(','.join(str(i) for i in sorted_only_space_sparated))
```

**Output:**

```
ec2ssmMaintWindow,AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole,ssm.amazonaws.com ec2.amazonaws.com
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: does it really sorted look the order `ec2.amazonaws.com ssm.amazonaws.com,`

Comment: Aah I got the question now. You also want the string to sorted which are separated by space.

Comment: yes, i edited question, need to sort only output i posted, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your string have both upper case and lower case use the key parameter in sorted method to sort the data irrespective to cases:

```
Services=["ec2ssmMaintWindow","AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole","ssm.amazonaws.com" ,"ec2.amazonaws.com"]
s=""
s+=" ".join(sorted(Services,key=lambda x:x.lower()))
```

## OUT

```
AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole ec2.amazonaws.com ec2ssmMaintWindow ssm.amazonaws.com
```

if the Services have always these 4 values then sorting the list will rearrange the index and make the index same for each time then you can simple access the value by its index.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i found another solution: i had issues because code in question is native python3 code (i ran it under python 2.7) and `obj.sort()` thrown an error that

```
unicode' object has no attribute 'sort',
```

i corrected code so it checks if obj is unicode

```
def get_user_group_service(element):
    s = ''
    for e in element['AssumeRolePolicyDocument']['Statement']:
        p = e['Principal']
        if 'Federated' in p:
            s += p['Federated']
        if 'Service' in p:
            obj = p['Service']
            if  type(obj) in (str, unicode):
                s += obj  # element is string
            else:
                obj.sort()
                s += ''.join(obj) # element is array of strings


        if 'AWS' in p:
            s += p['AWS']
    return s
```

Now values are alphabetically sorted on every itteration